# Efficient Subqueries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I'm definitely not particularly skilled in MySQL, but until now I haven't had to be. I'm dealing with a large database and, in particularly, a user table with 1500+ rows. So I need to figure out how to efficiently accomplish what I had been accomplishing with the IN clause.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM artists_profile 
WHERE artist_name LIKE '%$test%' OR id IN (SELECT profile_id
              FROM artists_profileltp_join
            WHERE genre_id IN (SELECT id 
                               FROM artists_ltp 
                               WHERE genre LIKE '%$test%') OR  
                                     details LIKE '%$test%')
```

Database with sample data

```
    artists_profile           artists_profileltp_join
+------+-------------+     +---------+------------+---------+
|  ID  | artist_name |     |genre_id | profile_id | details |
+------+-------------+     +---------+------------+---------+
|   1  | Jake        |     |     1   |       2    | rap     |
|   2  | Obama       |     |     2   |       3    | smooth  |
|   3  | Bob         |     |     1   |       1    | metal   |
+------+-------------+     +---------+------------+---------+
    artists_ltp
+------+-------+
|  ID  | genre |
+------+-------+
|   1  | rock  |
|   2  | jazz  |
+------+-------+
```

Desired results for $test = "ja" would return artist_profile ID 1 and 3 because Jake starts with "ja" and Bob plays a genre that includes "ja".

The tables are pretty simple.

Artists_profile contains all of the unique information about a user. Artists_profileltp_join has profile_id (int(11)), genre_id (int(11)), and details (varchar(200)) fields and simply joins the artists_profile table to artists_ltp table.

The artists_ltp simply has a unique ID and varchar(50) field. It takes 30 seconds on average to run my query. What can I do to speed this up and make my subqueries more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    artist_profile a
        INNER JOIN artists_profileltp b
            ON a.ID = b.profile_ID
        INNER JOIN artists_ltp  c
            ON b.genre_id = c.id
WHERE   c.genre LIKE '%$test%' OR
        c.details LIKE '%$test%'
```

`JOIN` would be better on this one. But unluckily, you're query will not use `INDEX` because you are using `LIKE`. I'll suggest that you read some article about `FULL TEXT SEARCH`

One more thing, the query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please read the article below to learn how to prevent from it,

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Beat me to it... only other optimization I was going to suggest was to select from C, join B, join A

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works great. One question though, how do I just return artist_profile? This query is returning rows from all three tables.

Comment: One other problem... Rows from artist_profile don't necessarily need to be linked to the other tables and I still want those to be returned... I've updated original query to show you what I mean.

Comment: see my updated query, by the way, can ypou giver sample records with desired result?

Comment: Thanks for the help JW. I've updated my original question with desired results.

Comment: @Colin can you tell, what is missing here? [please click this link for demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2588/3)